# Comma or no comma before "every day" used in this sentence?

Tags: commas

In the following sentence, would it be correct to use a comma to before every day?

> 1. We find loans for people with bad credit or no history of borrowing, every day.
> 2. We find loans for people with bad credit or no history of borrowing every day.
> 3. We find loans for people with bad credit, or no history of borrowing, every day.

And how would it change the situation if I changed the wording to this:

> 4. We find loans for people with bad credit or no history of borrowing, all day, every day.

Comment: Thanks for the answers Reg.  Good job it's not a maths site as there are only 3 possible answers, not 4. Also, that sentence isn't going anywhere near any inbox - it's for a demo project with a guarantor lender, and I just didn't want to  look illiterate :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

2) is grammatical:

We do x for a or b every day. Even if the sentence is long, it is grammatical.

My suggestion is:

- > We find loans for people with bad credit or no borrowing history every
  >   day.

Edit: after thinking about this, I prefer:

> - We find loans every day for people with bad credit or no borrowing history.

**All day, every day** sounds like you might be **bored.** I would avoid it.

The adverbial phrase every day has to go at the beginning with a comma:

- Every day, we find X for A and B.

In the middle, though here that would be quite awkward:

- We find X every day for A and B.

At the end with no comma as given in my first suggestion.

Cambridge Dictionary: They **usually** go in end position.

They sometimes go in front position especially if we want to emphasise the adverb.

[adverbs of time](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position)

[joke: Dear God of Credit: Please don't give anyone a sub-prime loan.]